# Fetching image from image-id android

Tags: android, api, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I am working on an android app to display the popular movies. I am able to fetch the result from the *themoviedb.org* API which gives me different values like movie-name, movie-poster-id, movie description, etc. Now I want to make another API call to fetch the posters. I already have one *AsyncTask* fetching the movie information, should I create another *AsyncTask* for images and call them one after the other ? Or there's a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask may not be the best solution; if the device rotates the activity is destroyed and when the async task finishes, it no longer has an activity to return the data to.

If you want to use async tasks, consider using a fragment with setRetainInstance(true) to do the network call. Your activity would launch the fragment and, if destroyed, it would remove its listener from the fragment and then when recreated, it would attach its listener again - the fragment continues to run regardless of the activity life cycle.

That said, you are probably better off with other solutions, like an IntentService or a full Service, depending on your flow.

Look at Volley and Retrofit libraries to help you with the network calls as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am working with Retrofit library